What is the name of this British movie?
A British movie. It's about an actress who has a sister who is a politician. Actresses agent is in love with her and wants to approach her by setting the politician sister up with his friend. His friend has some financial problems with taxes. Eventually, the politician and the friend fall in love, and she becomes British prime minister. The closing scene is the two of them with their children in front of the 10 Downing street.

Approximate year? Possible actors? Other scenes\plot points?

This is The Taming of the Shrew from the Shakespeare Retold series, which was produced by the BBC and originally shown on TV in 2005.  
It stars Shirley Henderson as Kate, the politician, and Jaime Murray as Bianca, her sister who says she won't marry until Kate does.  Rufus Sewell plays Petruchio who needs money so agrees to woo Kate.  They marry and eventually fall in love.  The closing titles are over a montage of their wedded life, Petruchio being a househusband while Kate moves higher in politics, ending with the shot of them standing outside 10 Downing St with their triplets.
